# Send data from web form to winforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Hello i have to develop an application in which im able to send some data(notification) from my webform to windows form and similarly from winform to webform.

Someone told me that i have to use web service for this purpose. so if someone please tell me how can i do that?

Im using C# for this purpose.

Comment: You mean web form as ASP.NET web application?

Comment: Yes an asp.net application

Comment: You mean that one user sends the data through WebForm (for example chat message) and second (WinForm user) gets this message and responses?

Comment: absolutely all i need is the communication between them

Comment: Similarly i need to send text files as well but only from winform application to webform?

Comment: You should look into SignalR (http://signalr.net/). It allows you to implement communicate between server and client and also broadcast message to client. And example of a chat can be found here: http://jabbr.net

Answer (score 2):

The general pattern from Web forms -> Win forms:

1. Add a WCF service to your Win forms application.
2. Implement the interface.
3. Use a ServiceHost and start the service somewhere in your initialization code.
4. Start your Win Forms project.
5. In your web forms project, Select References -> Add Service Reference.
6. Enter the URL in the Forms application's config file. (this is added when you create the service) the service should be discovered and proxy code generated automatically.
7. rebuild the Web forms project, you should have access to the Win forms service methods.

Services in the other direction are similar, but you don't need a ServiceHost implementation (IIS will host the service automatically)

You'll probably want further configuration as well. Possibly different bindings, and security.

Comment: I have never worked with WCF can you refer me some tutorial so i could follow the steps?

Comment: @user1467270 here's a good overall tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx

Comment: And i actually i need something like chat messenger in which i am able send/receive messages from web to winform and vice versa . Similarly i need to send text files as well but only from winform application to webform?

Comment: @user1467270 If both sides have the same service implementation (as a chat client would, I suspect) then you can create the WCF service code in a separate project/assembly, and reference that in both Forms/Web to reduce code duplication. You'll still need separate configurations in each project