# connect ASP.NET application to windows service application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have one windows service application and one ASP.NET web application, both created by C#.
Both applications get data from the database(SQL server).

Once I update database from web application, how could I inform service application to reload data from database?

Right now our solution is to use service controller to restart windows service application. Is there any low cost solution, like communication between service application and web application?

By the way, my boss hate polling method...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901908/send-data-from-web-form-to-winforms) and [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714513/webforms-to-winforms).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a table like a queue between the web page and the service.

When the page modify some data will flag new record in the table, the service will review that table each X seconds, if find a new record, will change the state and run any process you want.

Hope this help.

Comment: The right word would be "queue".  But the rest of the text here stands.

Comment: That's the idea, a queue.  Thanks Chris.

Comment: Yep. Polling a table queue works real well. Very cheap/easy to implement and very reliable. The only downside is that I really really dislike polling.. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I think it's indeed a good solution. But I'm afraid my boss might be dislike polling...